# On Windows how the docker host connect to docker containers?

Tags: docker

In the container, I can ping to other containers (172.17.0.0/16) and the host IP (192.168.23.89) and DockerNAT IP (default: 10.0.75.1).

But I cannot ping to the container's subnet gateway 172.17.0.1 and I known it's fine on Linux and it is impossible on Darwin.

Docker version: 1.12.0

So my question is: there are a way let the host can communicate with the containers do not via port mapping ?